# Passing a pointer to an assembly function

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I'm rather new to assembly programming.  I'm using the x86 platform with GCC (Linux).

I have a function that I want to call from C as:

```
myfunc ( unsigned char * s1, unsigned char * s2, int someint );
```

The function will take the s1 and s2 memory locations and compare them, then increment and compare, etc., doing some processing as it goes.  This is sort of like memcmp but I'm doing more.

My question: if I pass a pointer into an assembly function?
And then how do I say "give me the value stored at this memory address"?

Here's what I have so far:

To get the first function arg ("s1") off the stack, I do this (someaddress is a 32-bit integer, and I'm working on a 32-bit processor):

```
movl  8(%esp), %ecx
movl  %ecx, someaddress
```

If I put `somevar` into `%eax` (or `%ebx`, etc.) and then printf it with `%p`, I see that its address and the address of the unsigned char pointer "`s1`" I passed it are the same.  But I suspect that what I've actually done is taken the memory address, converted it to an integer, and then put that integer in someaddress.

For example, if I then do this:

```
movl  pos1, %eax
movl  pos2, %ebx
cmp   (%eax),(%ebx)
```

I get "Error: too many memory references for `cmp'".  I'm not entirely certain what that means, except "you screwed up" ;-)

So...

- how to pass a pointer in and keep it as a pointer?
- how to use the value of said pointer in assembly?  (e.g., like `*ptr` in C)

Do I want to look at the LEA operand?

I'm using Richard Blum's "Professional Assembly Programming" as my guide, but Blum doesn't seem to cover this case.

**Update**

Thank you very much for your learned response!

Unfortunately, I'm still not able to dereference.

Here is a simplified example.  The assembly function takes a pointer and should echo it back.  Instead I get:

```
first_ptr points to 81 (should be 81) <-- from C program
the value is -1543299247 <-- printf called from within assembler
the value is -6028513 <-- printf called from within assembler
my function returned -6028513 <-- return value printed from C program
```

C Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
        unsigned char first;
        unsigned char * first_ptr;

        first = 'Q';
        first_ptr = &first;

        printf ("first_ptr points to %i (should be 81)\n",*first_ptr);

        printf ("my function returned %i\n", myfunc(first_ptr));
        return 0;
}
```

Assembly program:

```
.section .data

msg:
  .asciz "the value is %i\n"

.section .bss
.lcomm str, 8

.section .text
.type myfunc, @function
.globl myfunc
myfunc:

  # save stack
  pushl %ebp
  movl  %esp, %ebp

  # save string arg from stack to "str"
  movl  8(%esp), %ecx
  movl  %ecx, str

  # let's try printing the ecx dereference

  pushl (%ecx)
  pushl $msg
  call printf

  # put the value of str on the stack 
  # and call printf

  pushl (str)
  pushl $msg
  call printf

  # now return the character at pos1
  movl  (str), %eax

  # restore the stack
  movl  %ebp, %esp
  popl  %ebp

  ret
```

Comment: Problems with your updated code: 
For printing the value, you are pushing 32 bits while the variable is just 8 bits. You can either extend it to 32 bits (which is what C does) or change the format string. Note that the low 8 bits of -1543299247 do in fact evaluate to 81, as expected. 
For the second print and the return: You are trying to use double dereference by writing (str) and there is no such thing in x86. The assembler should throw an error for that, if you ask me, but instead it silently drops the parentheses.

Answer (score 8):

At least one of the operands to `cmp` has to be a register.  If you're trying to compare the contents of two memory locations, you'll need to put one of them in a register.  How to get it into a register you ask?  Well you've done just that already with your example code.  This line:

```
movl  8(%esp), %ecx
```

Takes the 4 bytes at %esp+8 and puts them into %ecx.  In a C-like psuedocode:

```
ecx = *(esp + 8);
```

Hopefully that makes sense.  You can do similar operations to get your pointers off of the stack and into registers, and then dereference them, compare the dereferenced values, and so on.  Let me know if you have more questions!

Edit - your broken out questions:

1. > how to pass a pointer in and keep it as a pointer?

   You're already doing that, and your `movl 8(%esp), %ecx` instruction, or something like it will do everything you need.
2. > how to use the value of said pointer in assembly? (e.g., like *ptr in C)

   You need to use the `()` again - to load the first byte out of the pointer in `%ecx` from your instruction above, for example:

   ```
   movb (%ecx), %edx
   ```

   In the C-like pseudocode similar to how I used it above, this instruction is:

   ```
   edx = *(unsigned char *)ecx;
   ```
3. > Do I want to look at the LEA operand?

   Probably not, based on the description of your problem you've provided.  It is always possible, though.  `lea` works something like like the `&` operator in C.  As an example, this instruction:

   ```
   lea 12(%ecx), %edx
   ```

   can be translated into our pseudocode as:

   ```
   edx = &(*(ecx + 12))
   ```

   or more simply:

   ```
   edx = ecx + 12
   ```

   This example is a bit silly, since we're using a relatively uncomplicated addressing mode, but how about something like this:

   ```
   lea 1(%edx,%ecx,4), %eax
   ```

   which means:

   ```
   eax = &(edx[ecx * 4] + 1)
   ```

Often the easiest solution to these sorts of problems is to write your routine in C, then compile it and disassemble the results.

Edit 2:

Your example program seems almost right, but you're trying to dereference pointers in memory - get those pointers into registers first and you should be ok.