# Passing string as argument into a function in x86-64

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

So, I have a string that I need to pass to a function in x86-64 assembly code. Think of it in c as something like this:

```
char str[] = "Abcdef"

void fun(char *str)
```

How do I do it? Should I pass each character as equivalent hex value and pass to reg? I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: *This will help you :*

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188239/passing-a-pointer-to-an-assembly-function

Answer (score 4):

Well, your prototype says it all -- you don't pass a string to the function, you pass a pointer.  So the string needs to be in memory somewhere, and you put the address of that memory into the argument register.  In assembly code, this looks something like:

```
# declare a data segment object containg the string
    .data
str:
    .string "Abcdef"

# code to call fun(char *) with the string:
    .text
    movq $str, %rdi
    call fun
```

Comment: Hey Chris, what if I had string in an address say 0x1515ac15 and has length = 9. How do I pass the address to rdi? just pass 0x1515ac15 to rdi? That causes it to pass last 3 chars of the string to function.